# How to save .txt file to .R file in RStudio

Tags: r

I have a R code in a .txt file. I open it on RStudio. How can I save this opened .txt file in .R file?

Any help?

Comment: If you're on windows, just change the name of your `temp.txt` file to `temp.r` where it's saved

Comment: I change. When I open it on Rstudio gives me filename.R.txt

Comment: open explorer where the file is saved, from View tab on top of the window, check the box next to `File name extensions`, it will show the extension of your file which is `.txt` you should replace the `.txt` and write `.r` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RStudio, start in the lower right pane that contains the `Files` tab. For example, we'll rename a file called `sampleR.txt`.

First, select the `Files` tab in the lower right pane of RStudio. Then navigate to the directory where the file is stored.

[image]

Second, select the checkbox next to the file you wish to rename, and select the `Rename` button below the tabs at the top of the pane.

[image]

Third, change the file extension from `txt` to `R` and press the `OK` button.

[image]

The file list will refresh, and you can see that the file has been renamed to `sampleR.R`.

[image]

To load the file into the code editor, click the filename.

[image]